# How to filter a row in AngularJS based on data in a particular 'td'

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angularjs-filter

I have a table made in AngularJS and I am trying to learn **SortBy** and **Filter** options.

I want to sort the table based on data in a particular TD. I don't want to filter by inputting a filter manually, but I want to hardcode that filter to the table.

My current table is :

```
<table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in data | filter: testFilter">

        <td data-title="'#'">{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td data-title="'First Name'" sortable="'employee.employee.firstName'" filter="{ 'employee.employee.firstName': 'text' }">
            {{employee.employee.firstName}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Last Name'" sortable="'employee.employee.lastName'" filter="{ 'employee.employee.lastName': 'text' }">
            {{employee.employee.lastName}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Current State'" sortable="'currentState'" filter="{ 'currentState': 'text' }">
            {{employee.state.state}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Reserve to (state):'" ng-if="employee.state.state == 'Available' ">
            <select>
                <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                <option id="123">123</option>
                <option id="234">234</option>
                <option id="345">345</option>
                <option id="456">456</option>
                <option id="567">567</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the above table, I want the filtering to be done based on the :

```
<td data-title="'Current State'" sortable="'currentState'" filter="{ 'currentState': 'text' }">
    {{employee.state.state}}
</td>
```

`{{employee.state.state}}` returns several values. They can be any one of the following :
 1. Available
 2. Resigned
 3. OnNotice
 4. Blocked
 5. Accepted
 6. Rejected
 7. Shadow

I want the table to only display the states Available and Blocked..

My Controller is:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('employeeTalentPool', []);

//Routers
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('employeeTalentPool', {
        url: '/employeeTalentPool',
        templateUrl: 'partials/talentPoolEmployees/employeeTalentPool.html',
        data: {
            auth: true
        }
    });

});

//Factories
myApp.factory('employeeTalentPoolServices', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var factoryDefinitions = {
        //getAllBenchers: function () {
        //    return $http.get(myApp.TalentPoolBaseUrl + '/EmployeeState?state=Available&pageNumber=1&pageSize=5').success(function (data) { return data; });
        //            },
        getAllBenchers: function () {
            return $http.get(myApp.TalentPoolBaseUrl + '/EmployeeState?state=&pageNumber=0&pageSize=0').success(function (data) { return data; });
                     },
        reserveEmployee: function () {
            return $http.post('').success(function (data) { return data;});
        }


    }

    return factoryDefinitions;
}
]);

//Controllers

myApp.controller('getAllBenchersController', ['$scope', 'employeeTalentPoolServices', function ($scope, employeeTalentPoolServices) {
    employeeTalentPoolServices.getAllBenchers().then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
        $scope.testFilter = function (item) {
            return (item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'available' || item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'rejected');
        }
    });

}]);
```

Can anyone help me with creating a hard coded filter in the table that will show only those two states?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module("testApp", [])
  .controller("testController", function testController($scope) {

    $scope.data = [{
      state: {
        state: 'Available'
      }
    }, {
      state: {
        state: 'Available'
      }
    }, {
      state: {
        state: 'Misc'
      }
    }, {
      state: {
        state: 'Rejected'
      }
    }, {
      state: {
        state: 'Available'
      }
    }, {
      state: {
        state: 'Abc'
      }
    }, ];
    $scope.testFilter = function(item) {
      return (item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'available' || item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'rejected');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered" ng-controller="testController" ng-app="testApp">
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in data | filter: testFilter">
    <td>{{employee.state.state}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in data | filter: {state: 'Available'}">
```

The simplest way to do this is like above.

You can also write your own filter, as shown in the snippet

Comment: Am I supposed to create that controller?

Comment: Im new to Angular and Im still learning. So not sure if I should make a controller just for filtering. I tried it without the controller by just adding "filter:"employee.state.state == 'Available' || employee.state.state == 'Rejected'" to the <td>. But that didnt help :(

Comment: No you don't need to create the controller. I just made that so that I have some data to play with. I've updated the snippet btw. This should work

Comment: Will show you an example for a custom filter as well

Comment: It sorts only Available status. I need both Available and Blocked. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I can see its working in the Snippet. But its not in my application. Maybe the way I added $scope.testFilter is wrong. I dont know why..

Comment: My controller is :

myApp.controller('getAllBenchersController', ['$scope', 'employeeTalentPoolServices', function ($scope, employeeTalentPoolServices) {
    employeeTalentPoolServices.getAllBenchers().then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
        $scope.testFilter = function (item) {
            return (item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'available' || item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'rejected');
        }
    });
    
}]);

Comment: Could you provide more code? Maybe I can help out. Where are you adding the filter? Is the controller defined in your HTML?

Comment: Table :

 <table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in data | filter: testFilter">

Comment: The controller is a .js file

Comment: Could you add your controller code as part of the question? I can only think of two cases:

1. The data structure of your `data` object is different from what I have defined in my controller
2. There's some typo

Comment: Done :) I have added my complete controller and made the changes to HTML just the way I did in my application.

Comment: Sorry if i confused you. I am still having issue with displaying the table with both Available and Blocked status. Currently only available is getting displayed. I have updated my controller in the question as you asked me to.

Comment: Hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide an example for the Data returned?

Comment: Also, have you defined the controller in your HTML? I assume you have, as you're getting _some_ data

Comment: Yes I made a seperate JS file for the controller and I am getting data.... 

I have made all the changes as you asked me to but now only the entries with Available status are getting displayed. I am not getting any errors in log.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a mistake from my end. It should be 'Blocked' instead of 'rejected'. Thanks a lot for your help! Sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Nah, it happens to the best of us. Glad to be of help!

Comment: Thanks again :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571294/how-to-check-multiple-conditions-within-a-td-in-angular-table

I have raised another question and you seem to know my application best. Have a check on it and see if you can help me out there too... :)